# Как растянуть картинку только по горизонтали

Tags: android

Хочу поменять фоновую картинку в RelativeLayout вот так

```
Drawable draw01 = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.picture01, null);
relativeLayout1.setBackground(draw01);
```

а она растягивается и по вертикали и по горизонтали, а я хочу чтобы сохранялись пропорции по вертикали, а растягивалась по горизонтали.

Answer (score 0):

Не думаю, что это хорошее решение. Лучше добавить `ImageView` первым элементом вашего контейнера. А дальше [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17424313/7334652).